# can't get body message using imap_fetchbody as a html/text?

Tags: php

I am using imap_fetchbody function to get the body of the body as html/text

```
$message=quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2));
```

but when I receive the body all the body message are on the same line

For example:if I have the body message

```
a
b
c
d
```

it shows like this one when I get using imap_fetchbody() function

```
a b c d
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You know whitespace isn't significant in HTML right?

Comment: how can I show the output as shown above?

Comment: I've heard there's a nl2br function, that will change newlines into <br> tags so you can display it as text.  If it's an HTML section, though, doing that is weird.  Maybe you want part 1.1 which might be HTML instead?